# Fstream - getting specific lines following the first line

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

I'm trying to make a program that solves for the root of a given polynomial and I would like to use fstream to get the polynomial whose roots the program is going to solve. Basically, there's a text file containing some numbers like for example:

```
5  
3  
7  
-5  
0  
7  
-6   
3  
4  
0  
8
```

The first number will be the degree of the polynomial d,and from that, the program is going to count down from the value d to 0. The program is then going to output something like `"The polynomial whose roots you'd like to compute is 3x^5+7x^4-5x^3+7x-6"`, extracting the value from each line.

I was able to implement something similar to that but instead of extracting numbers from a text file, the user would have to input it. Said code is below:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int n;

cout << "Enter the degree of your polynomial: ";
cin >> n;
double a[n];
for(int m = n; m >= 0; m--)
{
if(m == 0)
{
cout << "Please enter the constant: ";
}
else
{
cout << "Please enter the coefficient of x^" << m << ": ";
}
cin >> a[m];
}
cout<<endl<< "The polynomial you entered is: ";
for(int i = n; i >= 0; i--)
{
if(i == 0 && a[0] >0)
{
cout << " + " << a[0] ;
}
else if(a[i] == 1 && i == n)
{
cout << "x^" << i;
}
else if(a[i] == 1)
{

cout << " + x^" << i;
}
else if(a[i] == -1 && i == n)
{
cout << "-x^" << i;
}
else if(a[i] == -1)
{

cout << " - x^" << i;
}
else if(a[i] < -1&& i!=0)
{
cout << " - " << fabs(a[i]) << "x^" << i;
}

else if(i==n )
{
cout << a[i] << "x^" << i;
}
else if(i != 0 && a[i]>0)
{
cout << " + " << a[i] << "x^" << i;
}
else if(i==0&&a[0] < 0)
{
    cout << " - " << fabs(a[0]);
}
```

How does one implement something similar using fstream? Thank you for every bit of help!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    ifstream mystream("textfilename.txt");

    int n;
    mystream >> n;
}
```

It is nearly identical to using cin except that you need to declare an ifstream.

Comment: So, I did that but somehow I get very odd results like instead of getting _6x^7+5x^5+4x^4..._, I get _3.24034e-317x^7+2.32434e-317x^5+4.32891e-311x^5..._  Any more insights regarding what I'm doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @BeepBop please post a full version of your code and I'll take a look at it